# GAE modules + Maven + Eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to run my ear project in eclipse: Run as -> Run on server. I get an error: Application directory '....\guestbook-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war' must exist and be a directory. I see a war file guestbook-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war there, but not a directory. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047290/appengine-modules-maven-error-during-devsever-goal-run

Comment: was this issue fixed? could you please post a self answer and close the question?